# Flexbox row wrap not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

using OSX 10.12.4 safari version 10.1 and flex `row wrap` is not working as expected. I have seen the other questions on here about `row wrap` not working in safari, but it has not helped me so far.

Here is my html:

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header {
  flex: 1 100%;
  -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
  -moz-flex: 1 100%;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vucuceL7/) is a fiddle example

Comment: Use the `<p>` tag?

Comment: @SankarshMakam In this case I just have text inside of the div, but in many use cases there are other things, like colored background and multiple inputs and I am used to working with divs as containers for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same in `.body` as you did in the `.header`.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 100%; /* safari fix */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. What is the reason for this? In Safari do I have to specify a width for the row to wrap onto the next row?

Comment: setting the flex-basis (at least for me) when using `flex-grow:1` it is just a fix for safari to wrap.